# Why is the route animation disappear when using RouteReuseStrategy

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-animations

The route animations are set in the standard angular way.

```
  animations: [
    trigger('rotateY', [ 
      transition('orderperformance => orderlist', useAnimation(rotateFlipToLeft)),
      transition('orderlist => orderperformance', useAnimation(rotateFlipToRight))
    ])
  ]
```

and in the markup

```
    <div class="modules-route-wrap" [@rotateY]="getRouterTag(outlet)">
        <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

They work well.

Now when the RouteReuseStrategy is implemented, the animations disappear even when the routes are marked to be non-reusable. Route reusing works well.

The reuse strategy is implemented the most standard way by customizing `shouldDetach`, `shouldAttach`, `shouldReuseRoute` etc.

Doesn't angular  support animations when RouteReuseStrategy is implemented?

Comment: Could you share the code for your custom `RouteReuseStrategy`? AFAIK, Angular uses a default strategy.

Comment: @AndreiGătej Exactly this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/route-reuse-strategy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-route-reuse-strategy.ts

Comment: I've noticed some errors while randomly clicking on the router links there(which is why animations might not work) and I think you should have a closer look at what you're doing in the `store` method. That's because the current route and the stored one but have the same numbers of children and the same configuration.

Comment: That stackblitz is only a demo of the route reuse and it has no animations. Here is more clear one. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-reuse-strategy-test-project. This is the exact reuse code I use again.

Comment: Yes, but in the your last StackBlitz you have a different reuse strategy. In the first one there were some errors that seem to be mitigated in the newer StackBlitz.

Comment: Yes. Animations are not working for the one which has no errors.